# Displaying 3D maps in ArcGIS JavaScript API 3?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, 3d-map

We are going to create 3D maps in ArcGIS Desktop with the help of 3d analyst extension and then I want to integrate those maps with ArcGIS Java Script API 3.2/3.3 (after publishing maps on server 10.1)

I researched on Google and ESRI help regarding display 3d map in java script application but not get confirm information although we do not have ArcGIS extension for Bing maps.

So it is possible to display 3d maps in JSAPI 3.2/3.3??

Software platform: ArcGIS Desktop and Server 10.1

Links that I have referred  :

[ESRI forum](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2396&t=298347)

[ArcGIS Extension for Bing Maps](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/bing/index.html)

Comment: As far as I Know, it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's not the ArcGIS JavaScript API, but there is ESRI's [CityEngine Web Viewer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#//010q000000nw000000), which uses WebGL.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will check and let you know (Not sure that its works with ArcGIS Server . I will research and let you know) thanks : )

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's in beta test. Here you can see a preview
http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit13/papers/devsummit-037.pdf
or you can use  CityEngine Web Viewer and generate output (file 3ws) with geoprocessing arcgis 10.2 from document scene sxd to 3ws creating a soe in arcgis server.

News: now in arcgis online you can create a scene (beta) and you can add map service ( see sample: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/12/15/visualizing-online-analysis-in-3d-scenes/ )