# 3D maps on web application

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, web-mapping, api, 3d-map

1)  Is there any web API which can show 3D trajectory below earth surface and can consume the ArcGIS feature service which can work closely with ArcGIS web platform.

2)  Is there any way to publish 3D feature service in ArcGIS Server 10.1 and can be consumed in web application and can be displayed on map.

Comment: This sounds like it should be two distinct questions. If you split them it may encourage answers from people to one if they don't know the other.

Comment: Please check this also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50010/is-it-possible-to-display-3-d-maps-in-arcgis-java-script-api